# Field with 4 elements, $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+X+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2, X^2+X+1)$. Show that $R$ is a field with $4$ elements.

It is $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2, X^2+X+1)\cong\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$.

To show, that R is a field I want to show that $(X^2+X+1)\subseteq \mathbb{F}_2[X]$ is a maximal ideal, but I am not sure how to do this.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an ideal with $(X^2+X+1)\subset\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_2[X]$.
I have to show, that $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{F}_2[X]$.

How can I tell that $R$ has four elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to show that $x^2+x+1$ does not have root in $\mathbb{Z}/2$ so it is irreducible since it is a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: Thank you. Since $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ is a principal ideal domain this is sufficient. It is easy to show, that $X^2+X+1$ has no roots. How can I tell, that the field has 4 elements? Is there a way to give how these elements have to "look like"?

Comment: It is an extension of degree 2 of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, so it is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2$, we deduce that it has  4 elements.

Comment: Is it always enough to look at the degree of the polynomial in these cases?

Comment: the degree of the irreducible polynomial gives the degree of the extension.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.