# Find out an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb Z[x]$ suct that $\mathbb Z[x]/I$ is a field with 4 elements.

Tags: field-theory, ideals

> Find out an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb Z[x]$ suct that $\mathbb Z[x]/I$ is a field with 4 elements.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381301/field-with-4-elements-mathbbzx-x2x1)  I get a similar question but I can not understand why  $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^2+x+1)$ has only 4 elements. I just need to show the order is 4 .

Please someone help ..

Thank you..

**Edit :** Now I have got the answer of it. It's because $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^2+x+1) \cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ and the later has only 4 elements.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is not a field with four elements, it is an infinite ring containing (an isomorphiuc image of) $\Bbb Z$. The other question suggests $I=(2,x^2+x+1)$ instead.

Comment: Maybe you mean $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/I$...

Comment: Try putting the prime number $2$ in your ideal and also a polynomial of degree two that's irreducible over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: yes yes that will be $(2,x^2+x+1)$ . I'm editing it now.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble understanding in the question that you linked? The comments explain why there are $4$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field with four elements. Two of the elements are (with the usual notation) $0$ and $1$. If $\alpha$ is a third element, then the fourth element must be $\alpha^{-1}$. A ring homomorphism $\phi\colon \Bbb Z[x]\to F$ is uniquely defined by the value of $x$. 
In orde rto have an epimorphism, we might simply pick $f(x)=\alpha$. Then let $I=\ker\phi$.
Clearly, $2\in I$ and $x^2+x+1\in I$ (because $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$ - why?), hence $(2,x^2+x+1)\subseteq I$ and in fact one verifies $=I$.

Comment: How obvious is it that this will be epi? I mean, $F$ is not cyclic abelian group, thus it looks to me that we need to use that $F$ is the splitting field of $x^4-x$. Is there a simpler reason I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The example you mention has $4$ elements because
$$\mathbf Z[x]/(2,x^2+x+1)\simeq (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]/(x^2+x+1)$$
is a quadratic extension of the field  with two elements $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.